# Perl FileSelect omit unused buttons

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit, perl-module

I am using the module `Tk::FileSelect` for file selection for processing. Below is the code I use to generate a FileSelect window

```
my $win = MainWindow->new()->FileSelect();
$win->Show;
```

And here is the window produced:

[image]

I think this window looks great, but there are two buttons that I would never need to use - the `Reset` and `Home` buttons so I want to remove them from the displayed window. I have looked at this [link](http://mkweb.bcgsc.ca/intranet/perlbook/tk/appb_13.htm) for list of configuration options but can't seem to find one to do this. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Reset` and `Home` buttons are not configurable in `Tk::FileSelect`.

If you really want this you can either patch the lib, or you can try to remove the buttons after `FileSelect` have created them. Neither solution being recommended.